# Intento obtener información múltiple de una expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy intentando enviar a la consola si el RegEx es verdadero o falso y una lista de las palabras que coinciden con este.

Intenté esto:

```
var mensaje = "Este es un mensaje de test";
var regex =  /(test|test2)/img;
var resultado = regex.test(mensaje);
console.log(resultado);
match = regex.exec(mensaje);

while (match != null) {
console.log(match[0]);
match = regex.exec(mensaje);
}
```

Pero con el código de arriba, la consola me devuelve:

> true

Sin ninguna lista.

En cambio, si añado otro "test" a la variable "mensaje", me aparece:

> true
>
> 'test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene en los flags del RegExp, en concreto el flag g, te remito a una pregunta de stackoverflow donde esta describen el fallo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results

Y esta pieza de codigo funciona:

```
var mensaje = "Este es un mensaje de test";
var regex =  new RegExp(/(test|test2)/,'im');
var resultado = regex.test(mensaje);
console.log(resultado);
match = regex.exec(mensaje);
console.log(match)
```

Te mando la documentación de MDN que te insta a que uses otras cosas en vez de esto:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/exec

Espero que te ayude!

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!